# Windows Store Apps StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync() causes OOM Exception

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, out-of-memory

I am new to Windows Store App development and I have an app written in C# that attempts to get the size of all files in a specified directory and its sub-directories.  The StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync() method works fine for directories with a small number of files, however with directories containing a large number of files it produces an OOM exception on devices with only 2GB of RAM such as many of the RT tablets.  Is there a way to go about this that would allow the app to to process the files in smaller chunks rather than building a list of all files (which seems very inefficient) as the code demonstrates below, any help would be appreciated...

```
StorageFolderQueryResult queryResult = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.CreateFolderQueryWithOptions(new QueryOptions(CommonFolderQuery.DefaultQuery));

folderList = await queryResult.GetFoldersAsync();
foreach (StorageFolder folder in folderList)
{
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery);

    foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
    {
        BasicProperties properties = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
        size += properties.Size;
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO, you've found a problem in Windows. I cannot imagine why file enumeration should be so memory hungry. I ran into the same problem when enumerating images in a folder; with ~2000 images RuntimeBroker consumes 4.5Gb of memory!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `StorageFolderQueryResult.GetFoldersAsync(uint, uint)` along with `StorageFolderQueryResult.GetItemCountAsync` to query the folders in chunks.

Something like:

```
StorageFolderQueryResult queryResult = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.CreateFolderQueryWithOptions(new QueryOptions(CommonFolderQuery.DefaultQuery));

uint numItems = await queryResult.GetItemCountAsync();
uint chunkSize = 50;

for(uint startingIndex = 0; startingIndex < numItems; startingIndex += chunkSize)
{
    var folderList = await queryResult.GetFoldersAsync(startingIndex, chunkSize);
    foreach (StorageFolder folder in folderList)
    {
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery);

        foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
        {
            BasicProperties properties = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
            size += properties.Size;
        }
    }
}
```

You can increase or decrease the `chunkSize` based on how you want to bound your memory.

Hope this helps. Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you, i actually figured it out in between posting the question and now, but you are exactly right.  I implemented just about the same code as you have here and it solved my problem.  Thanks.